# Two topologies are coincide

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $(X,\tau)$  and  $(X,\tau')$  are both  metrizable topological vector space, and let  $(x_{n})\subset X$ and $x\in X$ and  $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $\tau$  topology if and only if $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $\tau'$ topology . Prove  then two topologies coincide on $X$.

Comment: @user244115 You have asked this exact same question three times within the last three hours: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367445/coincide-topologies http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367608/when-two-topologies-are-same
please do not spam the same question across multiple posts. People will answer your questions, just give them time.