# How do convergent sequences in a metric space determine the topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

It is often stated that a metric topology is 'fully described  by its convergent sequences'. How can this be expressed in a more formal way?

Answer (score 3):

The formal statement would be

**Theorem.** Two metrics on a set determine the same topology if and only if they have the same convergent sequences.

Comment: Does this also hold for any two Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Very likely. I haven't thought about this kind of thing since grad school many years ago. Why not try to write a proof? I suspect it's straightforward.

Comment: Turns out not to be true: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76700/435462

Comment: In $\ell^1$ a sequence converges in norm if and only if it converges in the weak topology but the weak topology is strictly weaker than the norm topology. So, in general topological spaces, sequences fail to describe completely the space. If you use nets instead of sequences then it's true.

Comment: @DannyDuberstein: The spaces whose topologies are completely determined by their convergent sequences are the [sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Thanks for reminding me that you need to think about nets, not just sequences.